# What is the Visual Studio TestTools equivalent of NUnit's Assert.Ignore?

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

The title says it all. If I want to ignore a test at run time, I can use NUnit's `Assert.Ignore()` call.

However, I'm not using NUnit! There doesn't seem to be an `Assert.Ignore()` in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`. Are there any similar alternatives for Visual Studio's unit testing library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp. After exploring Visual Studio's Assert implementation, `Assert.Inconclusive()` seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Assert.Inconclusive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.Inconclusive.aspx) method which:

> Indicates that an assertion cannot be proven true or false. Also used to indicate an assertion that has not yet been implemented.

---

Source: https://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons.